# Accessing getExternalFilesDir within a WebView

Tags: android, html, cordova, webview

I have an Android app that writes video files to the folder provided with `getExternalFilesDir`. When I debug the app, I can see that they're stored in the folder `/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.my.app/files/`.

Now, within a WebView, if I point an HTML5 video tag at a file in that folder, it works... however it's hardcoded, so I want to get that folder name via JavaScript (since I assume it might vary depending on device).

I've been using `window.requestFileSystem` to get the location, however it seems to omit the `/storage/emulated/0` part and just give me `//Android/data/com.my.app/files/`.

I assume I'm missing something pretty basic. Any thoughts / opinions? Code follows:

**Java code to copy files:**

```
File path = getExternalFilesDir(null);
File file = new File(path, justTheFileName);
Log.w(TAG, "Location of File: " + file.toString());
try {
    out = new FileOutputStream(file);
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e(TAG, "ERROR WITH out = new FileOutputStream(file);");
    e.printStackTrace();
}
byte[] data;
if ( in == null || out == null) {
    Log.w(TAG, "Uh oh... " + justTheFileName + " has nulls...");
}
try {
    data = new byte[ in .available()]; in .read(data);
    out.write(data); in .close();
    out.close();
} catch (IOException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

**JavaScript code to access the filesystem**

```
function deviceIsReady() {
    window.requestFileSystem = window.requestFileSystem || window.webkitRequestFileSystem;
    var attempts = 0;
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, setFS, fail);
    alert("Requested fileSystem");
}

function setFS(fileSystem) {
    window.rootFS = fileSystem.root;
    fileSystem.root.getDirectory("Android/data/com.my.app/files", {
        create: true,
        exclusive: false
    }, function(dirEntry) {
        alert('dirEntry');
        rootPath = dirEntry.fullPath;
        alert(rootPath);
        // Test code.
        window.location.replace(rootPath + '/my-cool-video.mp4');
    }, fail);
}
```

I guess what I'm asking is... how do I get `/storage/emulated/0` from JavaScript?

(Please note that the app manifest XML file has the appropriate permissions to read/write already)

Comment: what version of android are you using?  are you seeing the alert('dirEntry')?

Comment: I'm on KitKat (4.4.2). Yes I am. The `rootPath` alert says "//Android/data/com.weever.streetsmarts/files".

Comment: try dirEntry.toURL(), this will give you a cdvfile:/// path (I assume your using cordova 3?)

Comment: Yep, Cordova 3. That gave me this URL: `cdvfile://localhost/persistent/Android/data/com.my.app/files/my-cool-video.mp4`, however that location doesn't seem to be correct... It can't find the file there.

Comment: but cordova/your browser should understand where that location is (see https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file/blob/dev/doc/index.md.) why don't you try using a html5 video tag instead of window.location.replace?

Comment: Hmm, yes, I just used a Directory Reader, and it sees all the files. I'll try a `video` tag again and get back to you.

Comment: I checked LogCat, and it's saying "java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider". The file is definitely there, so I'm at a loss...

Comment: I ended up using `dirEntry.toNativeURL()` to get the path. The Android video player does not handle custom URL schemes (eg, cdvfile://). See here: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=346718